# Uri of default sound for SMS notification

Tags: java, android, notifications, sms, ringtonemanager

How to find `Uri` of default sound for `SMS` notification?

I try to use `getActualDefaultRingtoneUri()`, but it use only 3 type:
`TYPE_ALARM`, `TYPE_NOTIFICATION` and `TYPE_RINGTONE`. And no one of this is not custom `SMS` notification.
How to find exactly `SMS` notification sound?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Uri defaultRintoneUri = RingtoneManager.getActualDefaultRingtoneUri(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), RingtoneManager.TYPE_RINGTONE); 
Ringtone defaultRingtone = RingtoneManager.getRingtone(getActivity(), defaultRintoneUri);
```

**edit**

Try with this :

```
Uri uri = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
```

And to play it :

```
RingtoneManager.getRingtone(getApplicationContext,uri).play();
```

Comment: No, don't work. Theoretically it should play my app sound. Practically it play something strange - music that is not tied to any application.

Comment: Dont forget my edit , this is what im using and it works for me

Answer (score 0):

To retrieve ringtone object use **RingtoneManager**

```
Ringtone ringtone = RingtoneManager.getRingtone(context, Settings.System.DEFAULT_RINGTONE_URI);
```

Comment: It's NOT Sms notification. It's default Ringtone for incoming call.

Comment: Thanx, but its doesn't work anyway. Nor Settings.System.DEFAULT_RINGTONE_URI, nor Settings.System.DEFAULT_NOTIFICATION_URI

Comment: I need play exactly sms default sound. Not notification sound, not ringtone sound - only SMS sound.